# OpenWRT: iptables rules will be deleted automatically

Tags: linux, iptables

In my OpenWRT instance, I have added iptables rules in the Input filter table, but the problem is when I turn on my system I found that the rules are deleted. What can I do so that the rules are not delete automatically.

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: why did you add your `ifconfig` output? That shouldn't be necessary for this question.

Comment: Contact your system administrator and ask them to help you instead of asking the same question twice. If you don't know who is modifying your iptables files we can't really help you. You could also [try to use Google](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Saving_Iptables_Firewall_Rules_Permanently).

Comment: @amccormack I add to the firmware openwrt the package iptables-save and iptables-store How can help me to add the rule to the table. thanks

Answer (score 7):

## OpenWRT

There are a few ways to edit iptables in OpenWRT.

### Direct use of iptables

OpenWRT will run the contents of `/etc/firewall.user` at startup.  It is a shell script, so it'll look something like this:

```
root@OpenWrt:/etc# cat firewall.user 
# This file is interpreted as shell script.
# Put your custom iptables rules here, they will
# be executed with each firewall (re-)start.

iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to 10.1.1.1:2222
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 10.1.1.1 --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT
```

#### Testing `/etc/firewall.user`

After editing the `/etc/firewall.user` file, you will probably want to test it. This is because you may be able to see any errors if you execute the script at start up. To test the script:

- First, remove any rules affected by the script. A `iptables -F` will work, but may remove rules you don't need to test.
- Next, run `bash /etc/firewall.user`. You want to see if there are any errors in the script. If you get any messages back, you probably have a typo.
- Next, run `iptables -L` and ensure the rules you wanted to be added were added correctly.
- Finally, restart the device. At this point you should expect the rules to be added just as they were last time.

### `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore`

OpenWRT (along with other distros), have a `iptables-save` command. By running `iptables-save > myrules`, you will have a file that contains all that is necessary to restore your iptables rules.

`iptables-restore < myrules` will read a file of iptables rules and apply them.

So you would need to create a `myrules` file, and then run `iptables-restore < myrules` on bootup. You can execute on bootup by editing the `/etc/rc.local` file.

More information on `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore` can be found [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-save-iptables-rules-or-settings/).

### Use OpenWRTs Firewall Configuration Syntax

The `/etc/config/firewall` file can be edited as well. The Firewall "provides a configuration interface that abstracts from the iptables system to provide a simplified configuration model that is fit for most regular purposes while enabling the user to supply needed iptables rules on his own when needed."

More information could be found [here](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/firewall)

### Other Distros

### Debian or Ubuntu

If you are running Debian or Ubuntu, you can try the `iptables-persistent` package.

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

The above will install the service. It will then save your rules to `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` and `/etc/iptables/rules.v6`.

You can get more info for Ubuntu 12.04 [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-ip-tables-on-ubuntu-12-04), Ubuntu 14.04 [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-iptables-on-ubuntu-14-04).

### CentOS

If you are running CentOS, you can save the rules by running:

```
/sbin/service iptables save
```

which will save the contents of iptables to `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`. The previous content of `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` will be saved to `/etc/sysconfig/iptables.save`.

You can get more info [here](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s1-iptables-saving.html).

Comment: thanks amccormack I did like you said but when I reboot I find  that the rules is deleted. and i change eth0 with eth0.2.

Comment: did you put your rules in there? I just put some sample rules in there to show where they go. I'll add a note about testing.

Comment: @ amccormack I have a project that is application is to add rules from the table in the filter web interface so I created a script that allows you to add rules in the filter table like this:
   try:os.system ("iptables -D INPUT -m mac-source --mac" + mac + "j DROP")
except Exception as e:
 print e                                       os.system ("iptables INPUT -m mac-source --mac" + mac + "j DROP")
  

I did not add the rules manually.

Comment: As long as you are using `os.system`, why not use it twice. Also run a `os.system("echo iptables -D INPUT -m mac-source --mac" + mac + "j DROP") >> /etc/firewall.user`. Also, beware of the blatant command injection risk in your `os.system` usage, be sure whitelist good characters.

Comment: I tried adding a rule in /etc/firewall.user then did ping from the pc to mac so I can do ping.              # This file is interpreted as shell script.
# Put your custom iptables rules here, they will
# be executed with each firewall (re-)start.

iptables -A INPUT -m mac --mac-source  18:CF:5E:FE:F8:61  -j DROP
~
~
~
~
~

Comment: And what happened? For the purpose of your question, it doesn't so much matter if your rule worked (because it could be an error with your rule), but it matters more that the rule was present in `iptables -L` after a reboot.

Comment: yes my aim is that the rule in this table iptbales -L but I can not find it after startup. that's why I made the test "to ping" to determine whether the rule at this /etc/firewall.user execute or non.@amccormack

Comment: I would use a test that is less complicated. Try `touch /tmp/test`

Comment: ok I did like you said and i did stop firewall and start and the file is not execute

Comment: Well the file should just be created. You would probably need to do a full restart. I don't know if restarting the firewall service is enough.

Comment: no the file is not created

Comment: Which version of OpenWRT are you using?

Comment: rampis, openwrt-na9xx-r25875-20121204

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24520/discussion-between-amccormack-and-kaio).

Answer (score 0):

You can write a shell script containing all of your iptables commands, then add a line to /etc/rc.local to run the shell script automatically when the system boots.  See http://bash.cyberciti.biz/firewall/linux-iptables-firewall-shell-script-for-standalone-server/ for a good tutorial on how to do this.